# Texcount error 'could not recognise package list'

Tags: hyperref, packages, geometry, texcount

using texcount in the command line interface produces the error 'could not recognise package list'. I'm using

```
texcount -1 -sum -inc mymainfile.tex
```

which includes several files in a two different subdirectories with the command `\include{mysubdirectory/myfile}`. This all compiles with no errors in LaTeX.

Edit: It seems that hyperref and geometry with \usepackage are causing the errors.

Edit: Deleted "The only related information I've found online is that texcount used to have a problem with packages with hyphens in their names (probably fixed since 2013), but I can't see a way around this to check."

Comment: The error should be produced by `\usepackage` or a similar macro which TeXcount fails to parse. If you add the option `-v` for verbose output, it should be more clear which macro produces the error.

Comment: @EinarRødland Thanks, but it just gives the same message, twice "ERROR: Could not recognise package list", ignoring it instead" whether I use -v -v1 -v2 etc

Comment: By looking at the verbose output, you should be able to identify which macro call (`\usepackage` or `\RequirePackage`) causes the error. Without knowing that, it's hard to tell exactly what the cause is and what can be done to either fix or bypass it.

Comment: @EinarRødland I understood that, but I hadn't understood not to use the other options with it, sorry. Now I can see that usepackage with geometry and hyperref are the packages causing the errors! Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Could you provide the exact instruction that produces the error? Or list the segment of the file in which the relevant macros is found?

Comment: @EinarRødland in creating a MWE I discovered that the errors are being produced by the numerous package options being written on different lines. I had no problems compiling this way in latex. Should I delete the question or just answer it myself?

Comment: I suggest that you write down your own answer in case others come across the same problem. In some cases, running TeXcount with the `-relaxed` option may help, but TeXcount may be restrictive in allowing options covering multiple lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently TeXcount had a problem with the options for these packages being on different lines in the .tex file. The problem was this:

```
\usepackage[pdftex,
plainpages=false,
pdfpagelabels,
urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
```

and the solution was this:

```
\usepackage[pdftex,plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
```